# Set PDF table cell width

Tags: c#, itext

[image]I am trying to create a table using iTextSharp library in C#.
What I want to set the width of the cell in the table.

I am using following code:

```
PdfPTable Ptbl_DetailsPerformance = new PdfPTable(7);
Ptbl_DetailsPerformance.SetWidths(new int[7] { 20, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 1 });

PdfPCell cellValue = new PdfPCell();
```

Now I want to dynamically set the width of cell but get error that "Width can't be set."

What should I do? Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't set widht at a cell level, only at the table (Width has no setter at PdfPCell level, if I remember well).

Hard to help you without knowing more about your problem. You can use colspan in ITextSharp , or calculate your "dynamic widths" at table level, but...

What's your need ?

EDIT :
itextsharp 2.050727  source ( class Rectangle : PdfPCell inherits from Rectangle, and doesn't overrides Width)

```
public virtual float Width
    {
      get
      {
        return this.urx - this.llx;
      }
      set
      {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(MessageLocalization.GetComposedMessage("the.width.cannot.be.set"));
      }
    }
```

Comment: actually i have few values which i have to show in the horizontal bars. So, according to the value i want to set the width of cell then fill the cell with color.

Comment: And I don't know hwat are the horizontal bars... Is that a simple table ? One row, multiple row ? Any print screen, maybe ?

Comment: so you can use colspans, no ? If the "array chart" is coming in the middle of a cell, then split your cells in 2.
Or probably better, use an ITextSharp Image, you can set it a percentage width. And colspan are setted to 5 in your "chart" lines.

Comment: Use the `colspan` as @Raphaël Althaus said. You won't find a program out there (at least none that I have ever seen) that will let you change the width a cell. Instead, you change the width of the entire column that that cell is in.